# Regrid Tile Map in Forge Viewer

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl, forge, tileserver

Can anyone tell how to render the forge viewer models on the map using the Regrid parcel data api or tileserver API ?

There are example of using the tile server API using the Mapbox Gl but it loads in a different div and I am not able to load the forge viewer models on the Map in the another div.

Any information is valuable!

https://support.regrid.com/api/using-the-tileserver-api this is the Regrid Tileserver API link